# Mysql php query returns no result but record is present

Tags: php, mysql

In my php script this query returns no result

```
SELECT * from `category` WHERE `desc`='".$desc."' AND Category IS NOT NULL AND Category <> ''"
```

PHP code:

```
$query_categorie=mysql_query(("SELECT * from category WHERE category = '".$desc."' AND category IS NOT NULL AND category <> ''" ),$dblink1) or die(mysql_error());
$categoria_trovata=mysql_num_rows($query_categorie);
```

But if I copy and paste the same query in phpmyadmin I get results as expected

What's wrong? I tried to escape `$desc` with `mysql_real_escape_string` but nothing changed

Edit: it only happens with this value into `category` field of the `category` table='PC/SERVERS - PRE MADE' which seems to be the only one with /,- and spaces

For all others records, including other records with the / characther, script runs fine

Comment: Can you show your usage in PHP?

Comment: Please add the resulting query of that concatenation. And BTW with Prepared Statements that is a lot easier.

Comment: `Category` might be a preserved keyword? Try adding the apostrophes.

Comment: @pbond: Do you mean a **reserved** word?  If so, a quick check of the [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/keywords.html) page of the manual would have revealed that `Category` is *not* reserved.

Comment: That SQL query is valid as is, assuming `$desc` doesn't contain single quotes. Can you show the failing query and your PHP usage?

Comment: If it only happens when their's a /, then  you're not escaping your SQL input. You need to use something like mysqli_escape_string or whatever is used in your database class.

Comment: `desc` are escaped, put the whole code.

Comment: This is my code, this happens only with one record into the "category" table which is filled with 400+ records. The record has a "/" into it, might be that? $query_categorie=mysql_query(("SELECT * from `category` WHERE `category` = '".$desc."' AND category IS NOT NULL AND category <> ''" ),$dblink1) or die(mysql_error());
$categoria_trovata=mysql_num_rows($query_categorie);
This works with 399 rows, and returns num_rows=0 for one

Comment: @Carmine Use `mysql_escape()` on `$desc` and then when you've got time update your code to PDO or `mysqli_`

Comment: @eggyal Snap, I said preserved. Reserved yes.

Comment: @JamieBicknell thanks but I tried already with mysql_escape_string and mysql_real_escape_string but nothing changes, num_rows returns 0

Comment: Backticks or not, I think 'desc' is a lousy name for a column/table identifier. What's wrong with 'description' (if that is indeed what it's an abbreviation of)?

Comment: @Strawberry renamed it with desc_cat in order to avoid any problem with reserved words but I still got the issue

Comment: Can you provide the actual generated query and the value of `category` on the record you expect?

Comment: @chris85 query is: SELECT * from `categories` WHERE `desc_cat` = 'PC/SERVERS - PRE MADE' AND `primary_category` IS NOT NULL AND `primary_category` <> ''. The row which should be found is: id=323,desc_cat=PC/SERVERS - PRE MADE, primary_category=PC

Comment: My presumption would be that the spaces are off or your `-` is a different `-` than the DBs. Try `WHERE desc_cat like '%PC/SERVERS%'`.

Comment: Why aren't you using PDO?

Comment: @chris85: if I manually insert ='PC/SERVERS - PRE MADE' instead of ='".$desc."' in the query the record is found, so it's some sort of weird encoding issue... how to fix that?

Comment: Take a look at [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).